# Postgres Conditional Query - Best Practice for comparing a string with several other strings

Tags: postgresql, select

I am currently using this to get my result:

`pg_prepare($tableConnection, "", "SELECT * FROM star_wars_action_figures WHERE cool = 't' AND weapon ILIKE $1 OR weapon ILIKE $2 OR weapon ILIKE $3 OR weapon ILIKE $4 OR weapon ILIKE $5") or die( $tableDataRetrieved = false );`

`$actionFigureTables = pg_fetch_all(pg_execute('', array("%gun%","%".$tagArray[0]."%","%".$tagArray[1]."%","%".$tagArray[2]."%","%".$tagArray[3]."%")));`

In English I am going for this:
Look in `star_wars_action_figures`, return only the ones that are `cool` and then only if the weapon contains `gun` AND any of these other weapons (`lightsaber`|`fist`|`knife`|`wit`)

There has to be a more efficient and reliable way to do this right?

I think this s a core simple question and need to get this logic down before I can progress.

Cheers!

Bo

Comment: I wonder if it's possible to pass [arrays](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/arrays.html) to a Postgres connection in Perl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postgres knows [POSIX regular expressions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-TABLE). Your query could be formulated as

```
...AND weapon ~* $1
```

if you pass `gun|lightsaber|fist|knife|wit` to the first parameter.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM star_wars_action_figures WHERE cool = 't' AND weapon ~* $1` Then pass in: "gun|lightsaber|fist|knife|wit" ? I could have used regex so many times!

Comment: Edited. I missed that the `'t'` was a constant in your question. Plus the syntax was wrong.

Comment: Yes. See [the link I already posted](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-TABLE).